# Azure data factory with a copy activity using a binary dataset fails to copy folder contents if parameterized

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, linked-service

In my Azure data factory I need to copy data from an SFTP source that has structured the data into date based directories with the following hierarchy
year -> month -> date -> file

I have created a linked service and a binary dataset where the dataset "filesystem" points to the host and "Directory" points to the folder that contains the year directories. Ex: host/exampledir/yeardir/

with yeardir containing the year directories.

When I manually write into the dataset that I want the folder "2015" it will copy the entirety of the 2015 folder, however if I put a parameter for the directory and then input the same folder path from a copy activity it creates a file called "2015" inside of my blob storage that contains no data.

My current workaround is to make a nested sequence of get metadata for loops that drill into each folder and subfolder and copy the individual file ends. However the desired result is to instead have the single binary dataset copy each folder without the need for get metadata.

Is this possible within the scope of the data factory?

edit:

[manual filepath that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R7Vf.png)

[parameterized filepath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSSDM.png)

[properties used in copy activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsvUz.png)

To add further context I have tried manually writing the filepath into the copy activity as shown in the photo, I have also attempted to use variables, dynamic content for the parameter (using base filepath and concat) and also putting the base filepath into the dataset alongside @dataset().filePath. None of these solutions have worked for me so far and either copy nothing or create the empty file I mentioned earlier.

The sink is a binary dataset linked to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.

[sink filepath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmmkm.png)

Update:

The accepted answer is the solution. My problem was that the source dataset when retrieved would have a newline at the end when passed as a parameter. I used concat to clean this up and this has worked since then.

Comment: Can you provide the images/information (dynamic content or parameters and its values) of dataset configuration for source and sink?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham I have updated my post with the information you requested. If you need anymore information I'll update the post as required. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify this: You want to copy each year folder present in `exampledir/yeardir/`. Manually you have just copied folder for year `2015` but the requirement is to copy all such folders(with files) into destination. Is this right or you only want to copy the `2015` folder?

Comment: I want to iterate over each folder and copy all of the sub contents within. So as an example the directory could contain 2015, 2016, 2017, etc until the current year. And we want to break it up by year so that the transfers can be done independently.

Comment: When you manually give path as `exampledir/yeardir/2015` you are getting the desired results right?

Comment: Yes, it copies the folder and the contents within. The problem is that we want to parameterize it so that we can use exampledir/yeardir/@dataset().directory or just @dataset().directory to pass in 2015 or exampledir/yeardir/2015 (with concat) and copy it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since giving `exampledir/yeardir/2015` worked perfectly for you and you want to copy all the folders present in `exampledir/yeardir`, you can follow the below procedure:

- I have taken a `get metadata` activity to get the child items of the folder `exampledir/yeardir/` (In my demonstration, I have taken path as 'maindir/yeardir'.).

[image]

- This will give you all the year folders present. I have taken only 2020 and 2021 as an example.

[image]

- Now, with only one for each activity with items value as the child items output of get metadata activity, I have directly used copy activity.

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems
```

[image]

- Now, inside for each I have my copy data activity. For both source and sink, I have created a dataset parameter for paths. I have given the following dynamic content for source path.

```
maindir/yeardir/@{item().name}
```

[image]

- For sink, I have given the output directory as follows:

```
outputDir/@{item().name}
```

[image]

- Since giving path manually as `exampledir/yeardir/2015` worked, we have got the list of year folders using get metadata activity. We looped through each of this and copy each folder with source path as `exampledir/yeardir/<current_iteration_year_folder>`.
- Based on how I have given my sink path, the data will be copied with contents. The following is a reference image.

[image]

Comment: I have followed your instructions and I had largely attempted something like this before but I had neglected to use @{item.name()} in the sink. The solution however, does not work for me still as it still outputs a single block file. I do however very much appreciate your help, this has me stumped as I can replicate the desired behaviour for any of my other datasets but not this one specifically.

Comment: Not sure why the procedure works manually (for exampledir/yeardir/2015) but not for the above procedure. If this does not work, then the workaround that you suggested is the better approach here.